# Semantically and syntactically redundant curly braces change compiler error message

Tags: java, syntax, semantics

When compiling the following code, I get no error message from the first if statement, but I get errors from the second one. Only difference is that the second if statement has curly braces.

```
public class Test{

 public static void main(String args[]){
  if(Math.random()<1.0d){
   int a=5;}

  if(Math.random()<1.0d)
   int a=5;

 }

}
```

First if statement:

```
no errors
```

Second if statement:

```
Test.java:10: error: '.class' expected
int a=5;
    ^
Test.java:10: error: not a statement
int a=5;
^
Test.java:10: error: illegal start of expression
int a=5;
     ^
Test.java:10: error: ';' expected
int a=5;
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes. You can't have a variable declaration as the sole statement of a statement block.

Comment: Also: "Only difference is that the second if statement has curly braces." - you mean the second if statement has _no_ curly braces.

Comment: @davmac Oops, yes, you're right, none in the second one. However, this doesn't explain why there is a discrepancy. If one is wrong, then why not the other? Or if the other is right, then why not both?

Comment: @DudeDawg, answered that in my first comment (i.e. the Java grammar disallows it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that the second fails and the first does not.

When you have `int a=5` you are declaring a new variable a. That variable is only valid inside the scope in which it is declared, in both these cases that means inside the if block.

When you have curly brackets around the if statement then you can have statements after that make use of your variable `a`. When you don't have those brackets there then you are declaring a completely useless variable since it will immediately go out of scope and be thrown away.

Comment: "When you don't have those brackets there then you are declaring a completely useless variable since it will immediately go out of scope and be thrown away" - yes, and furthermore the Java grammar doesn't allow a declaration as the body of an if statement, which is why you also get a compilation error.

Comment: Yeah, but in both cases I'm declaring a useless variable. Are you saying that the curly braces change something here? Are you saying that a declaration isn't a statement, whereas a block statement, even if consisting of only a declaration, is?

Comment: @DudeDawg They are both statements but the `if` defines what is legal to follow it and a variable declaration isn't on the list. Once you've entered the brackets then you are looking at what is legal to put inside curly brackets and as you've already seen a variable declaration is legal there since you can then go on and use it. A variable declaration inside curly brackets is *sometimes* useless. One inside an if statement is *always* useless. As a result one is allowed, the other is not.

Comment: The more you know. I got this weird error when forgetting curly braces.